# Does Orchard CMS support mobile rendering?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, umbraco, orchardcms

I am looking to make a decision between Umbraco and Orchard CMS. One feature I like in Umbraco is the ability to render to a mobile device such as an iPhone or Android device. Does Orchard CMS have this ability also? Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. You can have Orchard pick the theme based on user agent, mobile too. Try reading Bertrand Le Roy's [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/02/27/dynamically-switching-the-theme-in-orchard.aspx) about that.

Comment: You can also build themes that adapt to both desktop and mobile, with just CSS.